# Pulling data from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy ndarray that I made using numpy.loadtxt. I want to pull an entire row from it based on a condition in the third column. Something like : if array[2][i] is meeting my conditions, then get array[0][i] and array [1][i] as well. I'm new to python, and all of the numpy features, so I'm looking for the best way to do this. Ideally, I'd like to pull 2 rows at a time, but I wont always have an even number of rows, so I imagine that is a problem

```py
import numpy as np

'''
Created on Jan 27, 2013

@author:
'''
class Volume:

    f ='/Users/Documents/workspace/findMinMax/crapc.txt'
    m = np.loadtxt(f, unpack=True, usecols=(1,2,3), ndmin = 2)


    maxZ = max(m[2])
    minZ = min(m[2])
    print("Maximum Z value: " + str(maxZ))
    print("Minimum Z value: " + str(minZ))

    zIncrement = .5
    steps = maxZ/zIncrement
    currentStep = .5
    b = []

    for i in m[2]:#here is my problem
         while currentStep < steps: 
            if m[2][i] < currentStep and m[2][i] > currentStep - zIncrement:
                b.append(m[2][i]) 
            if len(b) < 2:
                currentStep + zIncrement

                print(b)
```

Here is some code that I did in java that is the general idea of what I want:

```
while( e < a.length - 1){
for(int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++){
        if(a[i][2] < stepSize && a[i][2] > stepSize - 2){

            x.add(a[i][0]);
            y.add(a[i][1]);
            z.add(a[i][2]);
        }
        if(x.size()  < 1){
            stepSize += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense! I'm sorry I wasn't clear. I haven't learned to think like a programmer yet. I'm a bio student that has to learn this. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you probably don't want to put your code in that class definition...

```
import numpy as np


def main():
    m = np.random.random((3, 4))
    mask = (m[2] > 0.5) & (m[2] < 0.8)  # put your conditions here
                                        # instead of 0.5 and 0.8 you can use
                                        # an array if you like
    m[:, mask]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`mask` is a boolean array, `m[:, mask]` is the array you want

m[2] is the third row of m. If you type `m[2] + 2` you get a new array with the old values + 2. `m[2] > 0.5` creates an array with boolean values. It is best to try this stuff out with ipython (www.ipython.org)

In the expression `m[:, mask]` the `:` means "take all rows", mask describes which columns should be included.

**Update**

Next try :-)

```
for i in range(0, len(m), 2):
    two_rows = m[i:i+2]
```

Comment: I don't understand how I can go over the entire ndarray like this. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I think that we are misunderstanding, its my fault, I'm not good with explaining ideas

Comment: what part did I not understand correctly? You might want to have a look at http://scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial

Comment: I think that we are misunderstanding, its my fault, I'm not good with explaining ideas.

please correct my understanding. I believe my array looks like this
    
    -1  0 0.29  
     1  2 2.96  
     2 -2 3.0  

so I thought m[2] would specify the whole 3rd column and m[2][0] would be the first value in that column? Basically, I want to grab the two rows at the top. I'm only using the incrementors because I want to only grab 2 rows at once, and the distance between them matters.

Comment: It might also help if you said what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: m[2] is the third *row* and m[2][0] or m[2, 0] is the first value of this row.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to grab the top two rows from a multidimesional array and perform some math functions on them. I want to move down my array in turn, 2 at a time. Sometimes it may be necessary to recall information from the past 2 rows if the current rows do not meet a condtion.

Comment: you can get the `i`-th and `i + 1`-th row with `m[i:i+2]`

Comment: For some reason my [row][column] is [column][row]. I tried simply reversing the suggestions you guys have given me, but it prints every value in that column. @user1250948, the m[i:i+2]. I managed to get this to print:

    for i in range(0, len(m), 1):
        row_one = m[i:i+1][:,0]
        row_two = m[i:i+1][:,1]
        print(row_one)

Answer (score 0):

If you can write your condition as a simple function

```
def condition(value):
    # return True or False depending on value
```

then you could select your subarrays like this:

```
cond = condition(a[2])
subarray0 = a[0,cond]
subarray1 = a[1,cond]
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what the true or false does. I am not completely getting you. I'm sorry, I'm still learning.

Comment: I mean, it depends on what your condition is. If you're lucky, you can express the condition using standard functions, such that it can operate on the array `a[2]` without an elementwise loop, for example `return value>0` or `return (value.abs()>0.5)*(np.sin(value)<0.3)` works elementwise also if `value` is an array without slowing the code by loops.